# Vue displaying large matrix crashes browser

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to display a large matrix that is constructed of 0/1, each cell is a div which could be black or white, when trying to display matrix of size 1000x1000 the browser crashes...

I am using v-for nested with v-for to display it...

how can i improve the performance?

Comment: Manually write the `render` function instead of using a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Vue-related problem, but rather a DOM related problem. You are putting over a million DOM elements on a page. A tab where I ran a test that generated a stable 1000x1000 matrix with empty divs and classes showed that it consumed 2.3GB of memory. It took quite some time to even render, and scrolling is very slow, which suggests that it is the browser that is having trouble here. Vue does not do anything in my test after having rendered the page.

[image: Edit Vue Template]

[image: Memory usage]

What you can do depends on the use case. If you just want to display data in a graphical way, consider using a canvas. You can freely draw on a canvas, and since you do not have to juggle around a million dom elements, the performance should be **much** better.

Other techniques include lazy loading, where you use scroll position to only load/show the rows that are in the viewport. This will reduce the number of dom elements, which should increase performance.

Alternatively you can limit the amount of data that is served to the user, by providing a filter or something similar. If a filter matches too many items, you can cut it off at a certain number of items you know will render fine in a browser and show a message that some of the results are hidden for performance reasons.

Comment: I ended up just using canvas